# SQL Server query WHERE LIKE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2022

I currently start learning SQL query in SQL Server 2022, I want to get `productId` and name with name prefix 'Chain'.

I try this SQL:

```
SELECT ProductID, Name
FROM Production.Product
WHERE Name LIKE 'Chain%';
```

And I get this result:

```
ProductID   Name
---------------------------
   952      Chain
   324      Chain Stays
   322      Chainring
   320      Chainring Bolts
   321      Chainring Nut
```

But I expected:

```
ProductID      Name
-------------------------
   952         Chain
   324         Chain Stays
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `SELECT ProductID, Name FROM Production.Product WHERE Name = 'Chain' OR Name LIKE 'Chain %';`

Comment: Everything to the left of `%` has to be present in the data to match, so you would need Chain<space>% to exclude Chainring, Like is NOT a word match function, it compares a given sequence of letters to the sequences of letters in the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Jerry Jeremiah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2193968/jerry-jeremiah) [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76997215/sql-server-query-where-like/76997278#comment135736518_76997215); here is the solution:

> ```
> SELECT ProductID, Name
> FROM Production.Product
> WHERE Name LIKE 'Chain %' OR Name LIKE 'Chain';
> ```

Comment: The part `Name LIKE 'Chain'` should be simplified to `Name = 'Chain'`

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is :

```
SELECT ProductID, Name
FROM   Production.Product
WHERE  Name + ' ' LIKE 'Chain %' ;
```